# How to show a Unicode character in RDLC Microsoft Dynamic NAV 2013 report?

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-nav

I added a textbox in RDLC report and set value of it to unicode character. but when I run report, I got only ????? sign.

Please help me to solve this problem. I wish to see the unicode character in report

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the solution. you  must change the textbox font in textbox property.
[image: select sylfaen in Font field]