# Special Character In RDLC Report Cannot Display

Tags: winforms, rdlc, windows-forms-designer

My RDLC report contains special characters. Some of the special character can display but some of it cannot display example below:

[image]

Supposedly it should display like this:

[image]

How can i rectify this issue? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: try this one brah http://forums.asp.net/t/1540105.aspx

Comment: the link is unavailable..can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show a Unicode character in RDLC Microsoft Dynamic NAV 2013 report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000306/how-to-show-a-unicode-character-in-rdlc-microsoft-dynamic-nav-2013-report)